# Function with declaration of variables

Tags: function-construction

Is it possible to create a function with declaration of variables inside. For instance

```
List1= {1,5,3,25,6}    
Total_Sum[list_]:=(sum = 0, Table[sum = sum + List1[[k]],{k,list}])
```

Or is type of construction not possible in mathematica?

Comment: like `Module`? p.s. `Total_Sum` is a pattern, not a head.

Comment: What Kuba means is that it is not allowed to use underscores in identifier names in Mathematica.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know Total_Sum was an identifier, I was just thinking of naming my function. But yeah, I think Module is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Or more simply, `Total@List1` or `Plus @@ List1` or `Tr@List1`

Comment: Also, in similar cases you may want to use `Do` unless you re-use the output of `Table`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to program Mathematica as if it is C, you could write

```
total[u_List] := Module[{i, sum = 0}, For[i = 1, i <= Length[u], i++, sum += u[[i]]]; sum]
```

but as suggested in the comments, there are very much better ways to do this.  I would suggest understanding them all.

```
Total[List1]
```

or

```
Plus @@ List1
```

or

```
Fold[Plus, List1]
```